# Disabling hot reload for vue.js website with raw-loader for production-like environments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-hmr

I have a legacy vue.js app running on staging and testing servers.

The problem is that Network console is spammed with `https://localhost/sockjs-node/info?t=1602594418799` requests in the browser and, of course, they fail because they refer to an URL that is not available in the browser.

I would like to disable HMR completely for some of those production-like (but not exactly) environments.

The website is being served with the following command:
`yarn vue-cli-service serve --port 8080 --mode production`

For some reason, `mode production` alone does not disable HMR.

I have tried different approaches as recommended on the Internet.

So,

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    liveReload: false
  }
}
```

disables actual hot refresh for `devServer` running mode, but does not disable HMR - still seeing those `/info` requests.

Another solution:

```
 chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
          options.hotReload = false
          return options
      })
  }
```

does not work in my case: 'Cannot set property hotReload of undefined', maybe because my project uses 'raw-loader' instead of `vue-loader`.

Yet another solution:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('hmr');
},
```

did not work. Don't know why.

One more solution:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

this works, no more `/info` spam.

But there's a problem. I need NODE_ENV like `staging`, `testing` and want to disable HMR for those.

How do I do that? How do I tell vue.js and/or webpack to treat NODE_ENV `staging` etc. the same way as `production`? Alternatively, how do I disable HMR based on some other custom environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems the best I could do was to run `yarn build` and then serve the dist folder on nginx or Apache or nodejs static HTML server.

Still curious, why vue.js (or webpack or whatever) doesn't behave the same way when I run the website through vue-cli with `mode production`.

It's unintuitive; I expected `mode production` to work exactly the same as after building the site and hosting on any other server.